# How to implement PencilKit in SwiftUI with background and zoom?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, pencilkit, apple-pencil

I am trying to build a view in SwiftUI that allows me to draw on top of another view, for example a table, using PencilKit. Everything must be zoomable and the elements of the background view must be clickable.

I thought about using a ZStack:

```
ZStack {
  CanvasView(canvasView: $canvasView)
  BackgroundView()
}
```

In this way I can draw on top of the BackgroundView and interact with its elements, but how can I manage the zoom? When I zoom only the canvas scales itself.

I thought about using scrollViewDidZoom:

```
extension Coordinator: PKCanvasViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        onZoom()
    }
}
```

To know when the Canvas is zooming. Then the SwiftUI View change as below:

```
ZStack {
    CanvasView(canvasView: $canvasView, onZoom: onZoom)
    BackgroundView()
        .scaleEffect(scale)
}

func onZoom() {
    scale = canvasView.zoomScale
}
```

This way the BackgroundView scales itself but only focusing on the center.
Is there a way to follow not only the canvas zoom scale but also the anchor of the zoom?

Or more generally, is there a way to get what I want?
I see many apps that permits to draw on top of some view and interact with buttons inside that view, but I cannot find any useful documentation about that.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution and if so could you share it?

Comment: @SwiftIsGreat did anyone find a solution?

Comment: I somehow found a solution, the SwiftUI background is zoomable and it works fine, but the background is not clickable.